# Regexp pattern to match (and remove) multi-line PHP code from include files

Tags: php, regex, string, templates, preg-replace

I'm loading a template file into a string for further processing (using file_get_contents). This template may contain PHP code which I need to remove before sending the reformatted template contents to stdout. The PHP code should not be executed, it should just be removed.

Example:

```
<h1>This is a template. This is HTML code.</h1>
<?php
  // This is a PHP comment.
  uselessFunction ('foo', $bar);
  /* This is another PHP comment */
?>
<p>This is more HTML code followed by </p><?= outputUselessInfo ('Blah blah') ?>
<h1>More HTML</h1>
<? echo "foo " . $bar; ?>
<p>That's all, folks</p>
```

I need to strip out all PHP code, leaving me with:

```
<h1>This is a template. This is HTML code.</h1>
<p>This is more HTML code followed by 
<h1>More HTML</h1>
<p>That's all, folks</p>
```

What regexp pattern would match all PHP code, either single line or multi-line, either long or short tags (and, e.g. by means of preg_replace, remove it, leaving no empty lines as a result of this operation)?

I've been staring myself blind at it but I can't see my way out. According to Google I'm the first one dumb enough to try this, because I haven't managed to find any ready-to-use patterns there.

(PS: I know the use of short tags in PHP is generally discouraged; I just want to cover the possibility.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regular expression (replace with `""`):

```
/\n?<\?(php|=)?(.*?)\?>\n?/ms
```

Explained:

```
\n?       - Tests for a newline
<         - Tests for start tag
\?        - Tests for '?' after the start tag 
(php|=)?  - Tests for the 'php' or '=' after the start tag
(.*?)     - Tests for any PHP code
\?        - Tests for end tag
\n?       - Tests for a newline
/ms        - Allows multiple lines
```

**EDIT:** [Fixed Multiline Support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: This is a partial solution, but when run through preg_replace() does not remove multi-line PHP code, in spite of the m modifier. Reading the regexp I feel it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: The s modifier. I should have seen that myself. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen Please select it as the correct answer if it works for you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one

```
/(<[a-z].*?>.*?>)/gm
```

but it takes out all html.

---

O.k., another [try](https://regex101.com/r/eO7gV7/1)

```
/(<\?.*?\?>)/gms
```

Now it should be following the assignment.

Comment: Now it really works how it should. Check my update and sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: It actually does. Less accurate than Jaques Marais' solution, but accurate enough. Just note that preg_replace doesn't grok the g modifier.